# Incorporating kernel into multiple regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, kernel-smoothing

Let's say I have predictors $ \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_m, ... x_p\} $. I want to fit a multiple regression using $\{x_1,...,x_m\}$, but give more weight to points that are close to a particular $\vec{x}^*$ based on a kernel calculated using a subset of the predictors $\{x_{m+1},...,x_p\}$. So something like:
$$ \hat{y}^* = \hat{f}(\vec{x}^*) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n K(\vec{x}^*,\vec{x}_i)(\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x_{i1} + ... + \hat{\beta}_mx_{im})}{\sum_{i=1}^n K(\vec{x}^*,\vec{x}_i)} $$

How do I fit something like this? I've read about [kernel regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression), but this seems to use a pure kernel without the multiple regression component (i.e., kernel-weighting $y_i$ instead of $\hat{y}_i$).

Comment: "Fit a multiple regression... give more weight to points that are close to a particular $x$" -- this is kernel regression per the link, or its extension, [local regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).

Comment: What you propose looks like a simple Nadaraya-Watson regression of that $x^*$ on the fitted values of an OLS model.  You'd be using that $x^*$ to predict $\hat y$?  Why?  Why not just weight the regression model based on the distance metric?  Hard to give feedback with the motivation you've provided.